# Suggestions for finding replacement interior tilt latches?

Tags: windows, latches

I need to replace the left and right window tilt latches on an older vinyl window but I can't find any retailers who carry what I'm needing.  I see there are numerous tilt latches that can be attached on the top of my windows to fix this problem but I'd prefer to replace the broken INTERIOR latches with identical or replacement parts, if possible.

I've included a photo of the finger switch on the outside of the window, but the latch itself is contained within the window.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.[image]

Comment: Can you identify the manufacturer of the window? There may be printing or a logo somewhere on the window, or frame, or between its panes. If a manufacturer can be identified, it may be able to assist you with parts.

Comment: Thanks!  Amazingly, only one window in our entire home has a label. American Home Company (Frank 1 of 2), Model 740H